# Load data from text file to dropdown

Tags: php

I have a text file and I have a table that will build itself based on the text file. The problem I am facing is words that are 15 to 20 characters or less are being skipped.

**My text file data is as follows:**

> model;solution;quantity;cost;selling
>
> bd45p;45" TV Smart LED-UHD High Res;1;5000;8000
>
> del;Courier Fees;1;500;950
>
> install;Installation;1;1000;2500
>
> atv582;Android Media;1;5555;6666

What is happening now Courier Fees and Installation row will not popup with data but the row will be there. Android Media is less than 15 characters but the row will show up with all the data. When I add more characters to Courier Fees and Installation they then appear. Am I missing something?

```
    $file = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    $parts = explode(';', $line);
    echo "<tr><td class='text-center'><input class='form-control c_model' type='text' name='i_model[]' value='$parts[0]' placeholder='Model Number' readonly></td><td><select class='js-select2 form-control c_solutions' style='width: 100%;' name='i_solution[]' data-placeholder='Choose...'><option selected='selected'>$parts[1]</option></select></td><td class='text-center'><input class='form-control' type='text' name='i_quantity[]' value='$parts[2]'></td><td class='text-center'><input class='form-control c_costing' type='text'  value='$parts[3]' name='i_cost[]' placeholder='Cost' onkeyup='update(this);'></td><td><input class='form-control c_selling' type='text' name='' placeholder='Selling Price' onkeyup='update(this);'  value='$parts[4]'></td><td><input class='form-control c_gp' type='text' name='' placeholder='GP' readonly></td></tr>";
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Hope this makes sense

Regards

Comment: please share your code that you have done.

Comment: _“Am I missing something?”_ – common sense maybe? Please go read [ask].

Comment: @JaykumarGondaliya - I have added my code above

Comment: @CBroe - If you not going to be of assistance, please keep to yourself.

Comment: i think you need to try like this `<option selected='selected'>".$parts[1]."</option>`

Comment: alert the values of  $parts after splitting the line and check what its printing.

Comment: @Ali786 - I have printed what part[1] is holding and it is showing all the values that supposed to be added to the table